# Postfix- Mapping an email address to two different destinations

Tags: postfix, aliases, email

I am using "virtual Domains" in Postfix as I don't want to setup a Unix user for each email. In some cases I wanted to forward the email to more than 1 recipient, so I inserted in `/etc/postfix/virtual` these 2 entries for the same email address:

```
person1@example.com    forward1@domain.com
person1@example.com    forward2@whatever.com
```

But Postfix only sent the email to the first email address (forward1@domain.com)

So I just entered one line with the emails separated with a comma:

```
person1@example.com    forward1@domain.com,forward2@whatever.com
```

It works but I was wondering if this is the correct way to do it (obviously it is the simplest)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the correct way.

See `http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html` and `http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html` for more info.